# Amd driver virtualbox issue crashed

Tags: virtualbox, amd-graphics

My PC is windows 10
Amd Radeon r9 280x
Amd fx 8350
Asus m5a78lm/usb3 motherboard
16gb ram

I run latest virtual box

I was running Ubuntu 17.04 in virtual box and my whole PC crashed and restarted with HARDWARE ERROR on windows as it showed in reliability center.
What can be the reason?
I had no graphics drivers installed.
I gave 2048 ram,2 cores,32 video ram and enabled 3d acceleration.

And also do I need to install my graphics card drivers on guest Ubuntu also?
Cause those are not available for even 16.04 on amd site.

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean the VirtualBox 5.1.20? #latest vbox

Comment: Yes I do mean that latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not need to install the graphic drivers on the guest. The guest is unaware of your real GPU. The other part of your question has not much to do with Ubuntu. It is either a hardware, a windows or a virtualbox on windows problem. You should ask it on [superuser](https://superuser.com/).